# Date formatter from YouTube JSON

Tags: objective-c, ios5

JSON YouTube is returning this date format `2010-07-12T08:22:07.000Z` I'm trying to adapt to my needs with no success. "T" in the middle and .000Z I don't know how to handle them.

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ZZZZ"];

    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString: [videoDic valueForKey:@"fecha"]];

    [df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NSString *dateStr = [df stringFromDate:date];
```

Thanks

Comment: Whats the output of the current code? just so I can get an understanding.

Comment: Try single quotes around the literal characters in your format string.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work:   [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000Z'"]; thanks

Comment: The output of current code is nil. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try stripping the string before your run it through the dateFormatter.

```
NSString *formattedString = [[videoDic valueForKey:@"fecha"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@""];

formattedString = [formattedString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(18, 5) withString:@""];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date = [df dateFromString: formattedString];

[df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSString *dateStr = [df stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: Glad I could help :) There may be more efficient ways that a NSDateFormatting master may know but if it works I say let it run :) Happy Coding.

Answer (score 18):

According this [manual](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems):

*snippet*.**publishedAt** is type of **datetime**
The date and time that the item was added to the playlist. The value is specified in [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ) format.

According ISO 8601 format you can write like this:

```
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
```

Where **SSS** is fractional second of three letters. And **Z** means UTC time.

Answer (score 2):

`setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.000'Z'"` 
worked for me

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer, please include how/why your post will solve the problem.

Comment: Because Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset, it needs to be escaped by ''